# Encounter issues when passing the exception tests

Tags: java, string, unit-testing, testing, exception

I'm very new to Java. The assignment is about extracting the first and last several characters from a string to a new one. My solution passes most tests. But I encountered issues when dealing with exception test.

Below is my code for solution.

```
public static String firstAndLastCharacters(String text, int count) {

    if( text.equals("")|| count < 0 || count > text.length()){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    result.append(text, 0, count);
    result.append(text.substring(text.length()-count));
    return result.toString();
}
```

Below is three exception tests I cannot pass.

```
   @Test
void should_throw_if_input_string_is_null() {
    final IllegalArgumentException exception = assertThrows(
        IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> StringHelper.firstAndLastCharacters(null, 0));
    assertEquals("The text cannot be null.", exception.getMessage());
}

@Test
void should_throw_if_count_is_negative() {
    final IllegalArgumentException exception = assertThrows(
        IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> StringHelper.firstAndLastCharacters("Hello", -1));
    assertEquals("Invalid count.", exception.getMessage());
}

@Test
void should_throw_if_count_is_greater_than_text_length() {
    final IllegalArgumentException exception = assertThrows(
        IllegalArgumentException.class, () -> StringHelper.firstAndLastCharacters("Hello", 100));
    assertEquals("Invalid count.", exception.getMessage());
}
```

I'm wondering how should I modify my code. If you think my code can be more simpler, you're welcome to comment as well. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first test, Java will throw a `NullPointerException` when you attempt to check `text.equals("")`, as `text` will be `null`. Your method should check for the `String` being `null` before anything else, and throw the correct `Exception`.

All 3 tests also appear to require the exception thrown to include a message. You can do that by using the constructor `public IllegalArgumentException​(String s)` where `s` is the message to be included. You will need to break up your `if` statement so you know exactly which problem was encountered.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. But for the including a message, what if I cannot add a constructor? I know try... catch... can use the getMessage() method, but for the throw statement, is it the only way that I can manually add the message in the parenthesis?

Comment: @upintheflame you already use a constructor when you use `throw new IllegalArgumentException();` There is no method for this type that lets you set the message after construction.